# How does Juniper vlan.0 work with policies?

Tags: vlan, juniper

I'm trying to understand vlan.0 and Juniper policies.

Referring to here: http://kb.juniper.net/InfoCenter/index?page=content&id=KB16667
According to the link above, it seems that if I use vlan.0, then if I add vlan.0 to untrusted or trusted, then every interface listed under trusted or untrusted is added to vlan.0.

If that is the case, then if I want to configure policies between two zones (i.e. trusted and untrusted), does that mean that I specify vlan.0 as my source or destination address if I wanted to use an IP within that vlan?

To clarify my question:

For instance, let's say vlan.0 has IP A in the trusted zone, if I wanted to deny traffic going from A to untrusted, since A is in the vlan, would I match the source-address of the vlan.0 or the specific the IP address of A?

Also referencing:
http://www.juniper.net/techpubs/en_US/junos9.5/information-products/topic-collections/config-guide-policy/policy-configuring-actions-in-routing-policy-terms.html